# How do I return different View objects based on different type identifiers in the Swift UI?

Tags: ios

How do I return different View objects based on different type identifiers in the Swift UI?

View is a protocol in SwiftUI and cannot be used as a return value.

```
func navigationAction(item: Item) -> ?? {

    switch item.type {
    case .text:
        return Page()
    default:
       return TextPage()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `some` keyword? I don't have Xcode beta installed right now to test this but if I remember correctly the `some` keyword is new in Swift 5.1 and basically means you will return an instance of some kind of view. So try defining your function like: `func navigationAction(item: Item) -> some View`. I believe this is how the `body` field of the new SwiftUI `View` struct works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AnyView to wrap the views you're trying to return.

```swift
switch item.type {
    case .text:
        return AnyView(Page())
    default:
       return AnyView(TextPage())
}
```

Also, make sure your function specifies the return type.  In this case AnyView.

If you're trying to return different views in a separate swiftui view then just wrap the switch statement in a group tag and remove the return command.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way would be to use the `@ViewBuilder` property wrapper in that case:

```
@ViewBuilder
func navigationAction(item: Item) -> some View {
    switch item.type {
    case .text:
        return Page()
    default:
       return TextPage()
    }
}
```